# SQL dll load error

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, dll

I have a problem with loading a dll file to the database.
My code is `CREATE ASSEMBLY some_clr from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\some.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`

and i get the following error.

> Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Assembly 'some' references assembly 'system.directoryservices, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed . Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

Comment: Tag your questions carefully.  This is in no way an assembly language question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the prerequisite first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might sound obvious but have you tried adding "System.DirectoryServices.dll" as an Assembly to SQL Server before adding your own one?  You can find it in "c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.DirectoryServices.dll".  Try that first.  Failing that, I've had some success before using ILMerge to merge any dependencies into my dll before adding it to SQL Server.